# groups acting on curves

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry

Can anybody help me to prove the following statement ?

*Let $X$ be a smooth, connected projective curve defined over a number field $k \subset \mathbb{C}$. Let $G$ be a finite group acting on $X$. Then the induced action on $H^0(X(\mathbb{C}), \mathbb{Q})$ is trivial.

Thanks for your help!